# Subversion / SVN: can I import into a local repository/directory?

Tags: svn, version-control

I am trying to create a brand new Subversion repository on my local drive, but after a successful `svnadmin create`, and the creation of the corresponding directory tree (conf/, db/, hooks/, locks/, format), I cannot run the `svn import` command:

```
> cd D:\TestPrj

> svnadmin create "D:/svn/test/"

> svn import . "D:/svn/test/"
svn: E205000: Too many arguments to import command

> svn import "D:/svn/test/"
svn: E205000: Too many arguments to import command

> svn import . "\\localhost\d\svn\test\"
svn: E020024: Error resolving case of '\\localhost\d\svn\test"'

> svn import . "file:///D/svn/test/"
svn: E205000: Too many arguments to import command
```

I try with local path syntax, URL syntax and Microsoft specific one, but none seems to be correct.

Comment: Don't use tags that are clearly not relevant.

Comment: See this procedure: http://subversion.apache.org/quick-start#setting-up-a-local-repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, step=by-step

```
svnadmin create "D:/svn/test/"
```

OK, if you'll get ordinary FS-tree of repo in this dir (I saw, you got)

```
svn import . "D:/svn/test/"
```

FAIL. According to [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html), format if import is `svn import [PATH] URL` (note the last word: **URL**). I.e.:

- if you have *some data* in . ("D:\TestPrj")
- if you want to add it into repository, placed at `D:/svn/test/` and not served by any SVN-capable server
- you **must** to use file:/// protocol and full physical path in URL without quotes around URL

<strike>I can't recall and can't test, have you have backslashes or slashes in path, you have to try it (starting from backslashes, I suppose)</strike>

> Remember that Subversion expects all repository paths in the form
>   file:///C:/SVNRepository/. Note the use of forward slashes throughout

```
svn import . file:///D:/svn/test
```

But I'll recommend perform (*before import*) two additional steps in order to make life more easier

1. Don't import into root, follow recommended repo-tree and create `/trunk` `/branches` `/tags` hierarchy in root (import into trunk can be performed without preliminary created trunk, because "Parent directories are created in the repository as necessary...")
2. Run [svnserve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html) in easy and fast mode (listen on 127.0.0.1, root is root of your repo)
   and import into svn://localhost/trunk (or maybe slightly different path according to *your choice*) and don't solve problems of physical path, quotes, slashes

Comment: See this procedure http://subversion.apache.org/quick-start#setting-up-a-local-repo